# Naive Bayes model cannot predict with python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Here this the code

```
bayes = joblib.load("D:/model/bayess.pkl")
datas = [profile_pict,  num_username, _fullname_words, num_fullname, cocok, _desc, url, private, __post, __followers, __following ,_rasio]
identifikasi = bayes.predict([datas])
print(identifikasi)
```

And the error:

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:329: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator GaussianNB from version 0.24.2 when using version 1.0.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. For more info please refer to:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bayes.py", line 132, in <module>
    identifikasi = bayes.predict([datas])
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 83, in predict
    jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 489, in _joint_log_likelihood
    n_ij = -0.5 * np.sum(np.log(2.0 * np.pi * self.var_[i, :]))
AttributeError: 'GaussianNB' object has no attribute 'var_'**
```

I did load the model using other machine learning models such as decision tree, svm and it worked, but, when using the naive bayes model, there was an error

Comment: This warning seems relevant: `UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator GaussianNB from version 0.24.2 when using version 1.0.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results`. You're using different sklearn versions between training and prediction...

Comment: thanks sir i didn't see